# Aren't teragen "rows" supposed to end with newline (\r\n)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, teragen, terasort

I was trying to assist with a (deleted) question, here at SO, about how to define an Hive external table over data generated by **teragen**.
According to the teragen code's comments, each 100 bytes of data (=row) should end with **\r \n**, however, It seems that it ends with 4 characters with hex values of **cc dd ee ff**

The full demo is down below.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

> /**  * Generate the official terasort input data set.  * The user
>   specifies the number of rows and the output directory and this  *
>   class runs a map/reduce program to generate the data.  * The format of
>   the data is:  *
>
>   *
> - (10 bytes key) (10 bytes rowid) (78 bytes
>     filler) **\r \n**  *
>
>   The keys are random characters from the set ' '
>     .. '~'.  *
>
>   The rowid is the right justified row id as a int.  *
>
>   The filler consists of 7 runs of 10 characters from 'A' to 'Z'.  *
>
> *  *
>
> https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraGen.java

---

Using teragen to generate 7 records

```
hadoop jar /usr/jars/hadoop-examples.jar teragen 7 /user/hive/warehouse/teragen
```

---

As expected, we get files with total data volume of 700 bytes

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/teragen

Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-03 22:38 /user/hive/warehouse/teragen/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup        400 2017-03-03 22:38 /user/hive/warehouse/teragen/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup        300 2017-03-03 22:38 /user/hive/warehouse/teragen/part-m-00001
```

---

Moving the files to local directory and checking the HEX values.

```
hdfs dfs -get /user/hive/warehouse/teragen/part-m-00001

od -v -Anone -w20 -tx1
```

At this point I was expecting to see `0a 0d` (\r\n) as the last 2 characters of each 100 bytes, but instead I see `ee ff`.
There are no newline at the end of the "rows".

```
 5c 90 ab 38 ae 52 89 62 15 d7 00 11 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 34 88 99 aa bb 41 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
 32 32 32 32 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 39 39 39 39 35 35 35 35
 42 42 42 42 31 31 31 31 38 38 38 38 44 44 44 44 cc dd ee ff <--
 72 dc 0c a5 1e 33 3f 32 4b 7a 00 11 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 35 88 99 aa bb 38 38 38 38 33 33 33 33 42 42 42 42
 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 34 34 34 34 37 37 37 37 32 32 32 32
 37 37 37 37 39 39 39 39 30 30 30 30 32 32 32 32 cc dd ee ff <--
 10 43 1a f6 a0 d8 47 b8 c5 5f 00 11 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
 30 30 30 36 88 99 aa bb 39 39 39 39 37 37 37 37 34 34 34 34
 41 41 41 41 37 37 37 37 45 45 45 45 44 44 44 44 41 41 41 41
 41 41 41 41 39 39 39 39 38 38 38 38 42 42 42 42 cc dd ee ff <--
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the output of your terasort is relative to that TeraGen which you are referencing in your link. If you open the terasort content from some other [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraGen.java/) you'll be able to see:

*Generate the official GraySort input data set. The user specifies the number of rows and the output directory and this class runs a map/reduce program to generate the data. The format of the data is:
(10 bytes key) (constant 2 bytes) (32 bytes rowid) (constant 4 bytes) (48 bytes filler) (constant 4 bytes)
The rowid is the right justified row id as a hex number.*

Following this description I compare it with your first link:

**5c 90 ab 38 ae 52 89 62 15 d7** - 10 bytes key

**00 11** - constant 2 bytes

**30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 34** - 32 bytes rowid

**88 99 aa bb** - constant 4 bytes

**41 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 32 32 32 32 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 39 39 39 39 35 35 35 35 42 42 42 42 31 31 31 31 38 38 38 38 44 44 44 44** - 8 bytes filler

**cc dd ee ff** - constant 4 bytes

So it is not the newline but just a constant 4 bytes produced by generator for every record.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the answer, I didn't forget it, I'll get back to it when I'll have some time to do some more investigation. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz No problem Dudu, hope my answer will help you to resolve your question